# Hash table implementation

Tags: c, hashtable

I just bought a book "C Interfaces and Implementations".
in chapter one , it has implemented a "Atom" structure, sample code as follow:

```
#define NELEMS(x) ((sizeof (x))/(sizeof ((x)[0])))
static struct atom {
    struct atom *link;
    int len;
    char *str;
} *buckets[2048];
static unsigned long scatter[] = {
2078917053, 143302914, 1027100827, 1953210302, 755253631, 2002600785,
1405390230, 45248011, 1099951567, 433832350, 2018585307, 438263339,
813528929, 1703199216, 618906479, 573714703, 766270699, 275680090,
1510320440, 1583583926, 1723401032, 1965443329, 1098183682, 1636505764,
980071615, 1011597961, 643279273, 1315461275, 157584038, 1069844923,
471560540, 89017443, 1213147837, 1498661368, 2042227746, 1968401469,
1353778505, 1300134328, 2013649480, 306246424, 1733966678, 1884751139,
744509763, 400011959, 1440466707, 1363416242, 973726663, 59253759,
1639096332, 336563455, 1642837685, 1215013716, 154523136, 593537720,
704035832, 1134594751, 1605135681, 1347315106, 302572379, 1762719719,
269676381, 774132919, 1851737163, 1482824219, 125310639, 1746481261,
1303742040, 1479089144, 899131941, 1169907872, 1785335569, 485614972,
907175364, 382361684, 885626931, 200158423, 1745777927, 1859353594,
259412182, 1237390611, 48433401, 1902249868, 304920680, 202956538,
348303940, 1008956512, 1337551289, 1953439621, 208787970, 1640123668,
1568675693, 478464352, 266772940, 1272929208, 1961288571, 392083579,
871926821, 1117546963, 1871172724, 1771058762, 139971187, 1509024645,
109190086, 1047146551, 1891386329, 994817018, 1247304975, 1489680608,
706686964, 1506717157, 579587572, 755120366, 1261483377, 884508252,
958076904, 1609787317, 1893464764, 148144545, 1415743291, 2102252735,
1788268214, 836935336, 433233439, 2055041154, 2109864544, 247038362,
299641085, 834307717, 1364585325, 23330161, 457882831, 1504556512,
1532354806, 567072918, 404219416, 1276257488, 1561889936, 1651524391,
618454448, 121093252, 1010757900, 1198042020, 876213618, 124757630,
2082550272, 1834290522, 1734544947, 1828531389, 1982435068, 1002804590,
1783300476, 1623219634, 1839739926, 69050267, 1530777140, 1802120822,
316088629, 1830418225, 488944891, 1680673954, 1853748387, 946827723,
1037746818, 1238619545, 1513900641, 1441966234, 367393385, 928306929,
946006977, 985847834, 1049400181, 1956764878, 36406206, 1925613800,
2081522508, 2118956479, 1612420674, 1668583807, 1800004220, 1447372094,
523904750, 1435821048, 923108080, 216161028, 1504871315, 306401572,
2018281851, 1820959944, 2136819798, 359743094, 1354150250, 1843084537,
1306570817, 244413420, 934220434, 672987810, 1686379655, 1301613820,
1601294739, 484902984, 139978006, 503211273, 294184214, 176384212,
281341425, 228223074, 147857043, 1893762099, 1896806882, 1947861263,
1193650546, 273227984, 1236198663, 2116758626, 489389012, 593586330,
275676551, 360187215, 267062626, 265012701, 719930310, 1621212876,
2108097238, 2026501127, 1865626297, 894834024, 552005290, 1404522304,
48964196, 5816381, 1889425288, 188942202, 509027654, 36125855,
365326415, 790369079, 264348929, 513183458, 536647531, 13672163,
313561074, 1730298077, 286900147, 1549759737, 1699573055, 776289160,
2143346068, 1975249606, 1136476375, 262925046, 92778659, 1856406685,
1884137923, 53392249, 1735424165, 1602280572
};
const char *Atom_new(const char *str, int len) {
    unsigned long h;
    int i;
    struct atom *p;
    assert(str);
    assert(len >= 0);
    for (h = 0, i = 0; i < len; i++)
        h = (h<<1) + scatter[(unsigned char)str[i]];
    h &= NELEMS(buckets)-1;
    for (p = buckets[h]; p; p = p->link)
        if (len == p->len) {
            for (i = 0; i < len && p->str[i] == str[i]; )
                i++;
            if (i == len)
                return p->str;
        }
    p = ALLOC(sizeof (*p) + len + 1);
    p->len = len;
    p->str = (char *)(p + 1);
    if (len > 0)
        memcpy(p->str, str, len);
    p->str[len] = '\0';
    p->link = buckets[h];
    buckets[h] = p;//insert atom in front of list
    return p->str;
}
```

at end of chapter , in exercises 3.1, the book's author said 
"**Most texts recommend using a prime number for the size of
buckets. Using a prime and a good hash function usually gives a
better distribution of the lengths of the lists hanging off of buckets.
Atom uses a power of two, which is sometimes explicitly cited
as a bad choice. Write a program to generate or read, say, 10,000
typical strings and measure Atom_new’s speed and the distribution
of the lengths of the lists. Then change buckets so that it has
2,039 entries (the largest prime less than 2,048), and repeat the
measurements. Does using a prime help? How much does your
conclusion depend on your specific machine?**"

so I did changed that hash table size to 2039,but it seems a prime number actually made
a bad distribution of the lengths of the lists, I have tried 64, 61, 61 actually made a bad distribution too.

I am just want to know why a prime table size make a bad distribution, is this because the hash function used with Atom_new a bad hash function?

I am using this function to print out the lengths of the atom lists

```
#define B_SIZE 2048
void Atom_print(void)
{
    int i,t;
    struct atom *atom;
    for(i= 0;i<B_SIZE;i++) {
        t = 0;
        for(atom=buckets[i];atom;atom=atom->link) {
            ++t;
        }
        printf("%d ",t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, along time ago I had to implement a hash table (in driver development), and I about the same. Why the heck should I use a prime number? OTOH power of 2 is even better - instead of calculating the modulus in case of power of 2 you may use bitwise AND.

So I've implemented such a hash table. The key was a pointer (returned by some 3rd-party function). Then, eventually I noticed that in my hash table only 1/4 of all the entries is filled. Because that hash function I used was identity function, and *just in case* it turned out that all the returned pointers are multiples of 4.

The idea of using the prime numbers for the hash table size is the following: real-world hash functions **do not** produce equally-distributed values. Usually there's (or at least there may be) some dependency. So, in order to *diffuse* this distribution it's recommended to use prime numbers.

BTW, theoretically there may happen that occasionally the hash function will produce the numbers that are multiples of your chosen prime number. But the probability of this is lower than if it was not a prime number.

Comment: so, does that mean, for each particular hash table implementation,  we have to test it before we say prime number is good than non-prime number? because in this case, non - prime number is better.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's the code to select the bucket. In the code you pasted it says:

```
h &= NELEMS(buckets)-1;
```

That works fine for sizes which are powers of two, since its final effect is choosing the lower bits of `h`. For other sizes, `NELEMS(buckets)-1` will have bits in 0 and the bit-wise `&` operator will discard those bits, effectively leaving "holes" in the bucket list.

The general formula for bucket selection is:

```
h = h % NELEMS(buckets);
```

Comment: hi, I have tried "h = h % NELEMS(buckets)", now, prime number's distribution is good, but non - prime number's distribution is good too.

Comment: As @valdo said, that depends on the distribution of the output of your hash function (and indirectly on your input data of course).

Answer (score 6):

This is what Julienne Walker from [Eternally Confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) has to say about hash table sizes:

> When it comes to hash tables, the most
>   recommended table size is any prime
>   number. This recommendation is made
>   because hashing in general is
>   misunderstood, and poor hash functions
>   require an extra mixing step of
>   division by a prime to resemble a
>   uniform distribution. Another reason
>   that a prime table size is recommended
>   is because several of the collision
>   resolution methods require it to work.
>   In reality, this is a generalization
>   and is actually false (a power of two
>   with odd step sizes will typically
>   work just as well for most collision
>   resolution strategies), but not many
>   people consider the alternatives and
>   in the world of hash tables, prime
>   rules.

Answer (score 0):

There's another factor at work here and that is that the constant hashing values should all be odd/prime and widely dispersed. If you have an even number of units (characters for instance) in the key to be hashed then having all odd constants will give you an even initial hash value. For an odd number of units you'd get an odd number. I've done some experimenting with this and just the 50/50% split was worth a lot in evening the distribution. Of course if all keys are equally long this doesn't matter.

The hashing also needs to ensure that you won't get the same initial hash value for "AAB" as for "ABA" or "BAA".